# Compare two numbers, ramdajs

Tags: ramda.js

Say I have two functions

```
const getMeanPrice = R.....

const getLastPrice = R...
```

What functions should I use to check if one value is greater than the other?

```
const isLastPriceHigherThanMeanPrice = R. ???
```

There is R.gt https://ramdajs.com/0.22.1/docs/#gt

But it only accepts two numbers. Need something that accepts two functions. Like

```
R.somefunc(getMeanPrice, getLastPrice)(prices) => boolean
```

Comment: You're probably looking for [`R.lift`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#lift).

Comment: Hm. Docs are a bit unclear. Could you show with my example?

Comment: Sorry, I commented when I was only on  my phone.  I added an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`lift`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#lift) converts a function that operates on values into one that operates on *containers* of values.   For instance,

```js
lift (gt) ([8, 1, 6], [3, 5, 7]) 
//=> [8 > 3, 8 > 5, 8 > 7, 1 > 3, 1 > 5, 1 > 7, 6 > 3, 6 > 5, 6 > 7]
//=> [true,  true,  true,  false, false, false, true,  true,  false]
```

A function that returns a certain type can be thought of as a container of elements of that type, so if we *lift* `R.gt`, it will also operate on functions.  Thus:

```js
// Dummy implementations
const getMeanPrice = R.mean
const getLastPrice = R.last

const isLastPriceHigherThanMeanPrice = R.lift (R.gt) (getLastPrice, getMeanPrice)

console .log ([
  [4, 5, 6],
  [6, 5, 4],
  [8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9],
  [8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0]
].map(a => `[${a.join(', ')}] ==> ${isLastPriceHigherThanMeanPrice(a)}`).join('\n'))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

`lift` will work with any [`Apply`](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#apply) type, meaning one that has lawful `ap` and `map` functions defined.  This include arrays, functions, and many other useful types, such as most implementations of `Maybe`, `Either`, `Future`, and many others.

Comment: Great stuff! You should have this on the docs. Much easier example.

Comment: holy shift, you're a ramda god

Comment: @YasserNascimento: I forgot to this time, but I usually include a disclaimer on Ramda questions, noting that I'm one of the founders of the library.